How exactly to use StadiaMaps instead of Stamen on cartopy?
I followed some of the suggestions that were posted online but I'm getting
HTTP Error 404: Not Found

with my below test script (Note-my actual API-key from StadiaMaps is replaced with X below):
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
from cartopy.io.img_tiles import Stamen
import cartopy.io.img_tiles as cimgt
class Stamen(cimgt.Stamen):
    def _image_url(self, tile):
         x,y,z = tile
         url = "https://tiles.stadiamaps.com/tiles/stamen_terrain_background/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png?api_key={XXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXX}"
         return url
def main():
    tiler = Stamen('terrain_background')
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))
    ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
    ax.set_extent([32.08, 45, 12, 32], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
    ax.add_image(tiler, 8)
    ax.scatter(36.116, 25.772, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(), marker='.', s=1200, c='purple')
    ax.scatter(40.743, 18.58, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(), marker='.', s=300, c='purple')
    ax.scatter(37.929, 22.046, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(), marker='.', s=50, c='purple')
    ax.scatter(34.507, 27.897, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(), marker='.', s=300, c='purple')
    ax.scatter(39.799, 17.996, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(), marker='.', s=1800, c='purple')
    ax.scatter(38.781, 20.525, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(), marker='.', s=600, c='purple')
    ax.coastlines(resolution='10m')
    plt.gcf().set_size_inches(20,10)
    plt.savefig("test_RedSeaMap_HiRes.png", dpi=600)
    plt.savefig("test_RedSeaMap_HiRes.jpg", dpi=600)
    plt.savefig("test_RedSeaMap_HiRes.svg")
    plt.show()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

I've also made the following modifications to conda_new_cartopy_env/lib/python3.12/site-packages/cartopy/io/img_tiles.py
def __init__(self, style='toner',
                 desired_tile_form=None, cache=False):
        warnings.warn("The Stamen styles are no longer served by Stamen and "
                      "are now served by Stadia Maps. Please use the "
                      "StadiaMapsTiles class instead.")

        # preset layer configuration
        layer_config = {
          'terrain':            {'extension': 'png', 'opaque': True},
          'terrain_background': {'extension': 'png', 'opaque': True},
          'terrain_labels':     {'extension': 'png', 'opaque': False},
          'terrain_lines':      {'extension': 'png', 'opaque': False},
          'toner_background':   {'extension': 'png', 'opaque': True},
          'toner':              {'extension': 'png', 'opaque': True},
          'toner_hybrid':       {'extension': 'png', 'opaque': False},
          'toner_labels':       {'extension': 'png', 'opaque': False},
          'toner_lines':        {'extension': 'png', 'opaque': False},
          'toner_lite':         {'extension': 'png', 'opaque': True},
          'watercolor':         {'extension': 'jpg', 'opaque': True},
        }

 def _image_url(self, tile):
        x, y, z = tile
        return 'http://tile.stamen.com/' + \
            f'{self.style}/{z}/{x}/{y}.{self.extension}' + \
            'myapikeyXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXX'


Answered at https://github.com/SciTools/cartopy/issues/2419
